# Selecting a good and stable IPv6 tunnel broker?

Tags: networking, ipv6, tunnel

I'm looking for a good and stable [IPv6 tunnel broker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers), to be used from Germany. For example [Sixxs](http://www.sixxs.net/) and [Hurricane](http://www.he.net/) seem to be popular choices.

What qualities should one look for when selecting a tunnel broker, and are there big differences between the service quality between different providers?

Answer (score 5):

1. v6 connectivity - Who do they peer with and how?  Are they native v6 across their network and are they peering with other native v6 networks, or are they stringing together a series of tunnels.
2. v4 connectivity - how far is your tunnel going to have to traverse.  Same questions as above, but for v4
3. Automation - if this is your first experience with v6, there's going to be a learning curve, and having the ability to quickly change the tunnel settings is handy
4. BGP - depending on what you're using this for, you may want to announce your own v6 space, not all tunnel brokers allow this

Hurricane Electric meets all these.  I've been running a few tunnels through them for a while now and have had no problems that weren't of my own making ;)

Comment: And, FYI, HE has a tunnel broker in Germany